# Windows 10: How to add Network Command Shell (netsh) to Firewall whitelist?

Tags: windows-10, networking, proxy, firewall, netsh

I use the netsh interface portproxy command to proxy connection into my VM. However, Windows Firewall blocks the connection.

I know I can use the netsh advfirewall command to poke a hole. But I would rather Windows Firewall simply permit all the ports I use netsh to proxy. I tried adding netsh.exe to the allowed list but it does not seem to make any difference. What should I do to permit incoming traffic to netsh portproxy?

Comment: Did you go to Advanced Settings and change Inbound Rules?

Comment: Yes, tried that.

Comment: Please add in detail what you did to add it to the white list so far (e.g. screenshots of the current settings). Otherwise it is impossible to locate the problem. What tests have you done, what problems have you already excluded?